# Will visa officials compare the travel history in my passport to my employer's confirmation of my employment?

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, indian-citizens, canada

I am an Indian citizen and Canadian PR, wanting to get a Schengen visa from Austria.

I worked abroad remotely for 6-7 months (without informing my employer) because my friend had a serious illness and really needed me.

I am applying for an Austrian visa, and in the Schengen form they need "employment details".

Since they will need my passport for stamping, would it be possible that they call my employer and ask for my employment history, and as the "passport history" section says abroad, and the employer says "Canada", could it be a cause for concern?

I am employed and have a letter that says I was working in Canada during that time.

Answer (score 2):

They can do that, but I seriously doubt they do it so thoroughly. Most likely they won't bother with a Canadian permanent resident and they will approve it without hassle. I also imagine the Austrian consulates in Canada to have a much higher visa approval rate than the ones inside India.
That said, I can't tell for sure because I don't have any insider knowledge within the consulate.

Comment: "I also imagine the Austrian consulates in Canada to have a much higher visa approval rate than the ones inside India": that's probably true, but I doubt it has any bearing on any applicant's chances depending on where they apply.  The differing approval rates probably reflect the different circumstances of the respective applicant pools rather than a difference in the decision-making process.

Comment: Ok, (let's assume) even if they decide to contact the employer, and "get" the employment location history from them. 

1) Would they just make my decision and close the file? 
Or, 2) could they also inform the employer that the location history does not match with the passport travel history?
I am just nervous.

Comment: Does this help me? https://travel.gc.ca/assistance/emergency-info/consular/standards 
"Consular officials are committed to protecting your privacy rights. The personal information they collect is safeguarded against inappropriate disclosure under the provisions of the federal Privacy Act."

Comment: They are not allowed to disclose your travel history to your employer, but they can check with your employer if your employment details are correct.